# Standard LWC Tree vs Custom Tree

Tags: lightning-web-components

**THE ISSUE**

We have implemented lwc standard tree. The tree is very limited in terms of the contents you can implement.

For example, we want to use the owner photo instead of the name or a custom link to reference another record.

**THE QUESTIONS**

1. Dou you know if there is any option to show, for example, an image using standard tree?
2. Do you know any appexchange lightning component to do this?
3. Do you know any js library we can implement in lwc?

Thanks in advance. Robert

Answer (score 0):

If you requirement is this custom Why not make your own tree using SLDS?

There is standard template for [SLDS-tree](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/components/trees/), you can alter this, add support for images and much more.